# async await geocode api call within map with bottleneck

Tags: async-await, promise, gatsby, bottleneck

i'm using geocode api which have 10 request per second with in gatsby, i'm creating pages during `develop`, inside map function i'm calling geocode api to get the `lat`,`lon` from address to pass it to `context` for each page

but i'm hitting api limit 10 request per second, tried with [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck)

but i think i'm doing it wrong, because page creation failed
`"gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the createPages lifecycle:`

```
const getAllData = async () =>
  Promise.all(
   //data from graphql 
    data.map(async (node) => {

      //googleapi function send fetch request to  api  
      const geo = await limiter.schedule(() => googleapi({ address }));

      results = await anotherapi_base_on_res(res.latitude, res.longitude);

      return {
        path: `/${slug}`,
        component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/abc.js`),
        context: {
          slug: node.url,
        },
      };
    })
  );
const dataResult = await getAllData();
```

pages are not being created, is it the right way to use Bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

Pages are created when you run the `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build` commands, on runtime, once. I'm afraid this approach will never work as is.

More details about [`createPage` API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/actions/#createPage):

> Create pages dynamically. **This extension point is called only after
> the initial sourcing** and transformation of nodes plus creation of the
> GraphQL schema are complete so you can query your data in order to
> create pages

---

> i want to pass longitude and latitude to context

There are a lot of implementations detail lacking, but I think I get what you are trying to do. I think your code should look like:

```
const path = require("path");

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;

  // somewhere you are getting the data in a GraphQL query

  data.forEach(node=> {
    const geo = await limiter.schedule(() => googleapi({ address }));

    const { latitude, longitude } = someFancyFunction(res.latitude, res.longitude)

    createPage({
      path: `/${slug}`,
      component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/abc.js`),
      context: {
        slug: node.url,
        latitude, 
        longitude
      },
    });
  });
};


const someFancyFunction = async () => {
   return await anotherapi_base_on_res(res.latitude, res.longitude);
}
```

The idea, once you get your data (I assume is a GraphQL query) is to loop through it but using a `forEach`, not a `map` since you don't want to return an array, you just want to `createPage` for each node, as [Gatsby docs points out](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#creating-pages-in-gatsby-nodejs).

However, using a `forEach` you won't be able to use an `async` modifier, so you will need to change your workaround/approach to call an `async` function externally with the needed data (`someFancyFunction`), assuming it returns a `latitude` and `longitude` variables (tweak it accordingly). After that, can pass your data via context into your template.

Another workaround would be doing the loop to get the coordinates before the `forEach` (using an `async` `map` if needed or a `for..of`, etc.) to set an array of coordinates, then you can provide that data to the template for the corresponding position.

Comment: Thanks @Ferran ... this code is from gatsby-node.js, i want to pass  `longitude` and `latitude` to `context` .. but hitting api call limiit

Comment: updated the question, please check

Comment: I updated the answer. There are *a lot* implementation details missing, but the main reason your code is failing is that `createPage` should be called in a `forEach` not a `map` loop. Moreover, I'm not sure about the `async`  in your approach and because that implementation details missing it's difficult to provide a complete snippet. Option 1) Inside the `forEach` call an external `async` function to get the coordinates. Option 2) Do the loop before to get the full coordinates and assign them to a node, then `createPage` for each node and provide that data